# ¿Como compruebo cada color de cada pixel en tiempo real?

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un programa que detecta el color de los pixeles de toda la pantalla. Esto lo hago así:

1.- Tomo una captura de pantalla.
2. Mediante un bucle hago un `GetPixel` para saber el color de cada pixel.

Aqui el codigo:

```
    public static void TakeScreenShot()
            {
                bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
                Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
                gr.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bmp.Size);
            }

public static void SearchPixel()
        {
            //Toma la captura de pantalla y guardala en bmp
            TakeScreenShot();

            //La cantidad de pixeles x e y del bmp

            int PX = bmp.Width; //Pixeles en X
            int PY = bmp.Height; // Pixeles en Y

            //Pixel search esta activo?

            if(PixelSearchActivo == true)
            {
                //Este bucle comprueba cada uno del color de los pixeles
                for (int x = 0; x < PX; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < PY; y++)
                    {
                        Color pixelColor = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);

                        //Que color tengo que buscar?

                        switch (ColorSelected)
                        {

                            //Si el pixel tiene este mismo color entonces el cursor va ir hacia el pixel
                            case 0:

                                if (pixelColor == Amarillo_Protanopia)
                                {
                                    if(Detener == false)
                                    {
                                        Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
                                        Clases.clicks(0);
                                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        break;
                                        
                                    }
                                }

                                break;

                            case 1:

                                if (pixelColor == Amarillo_Deuteranopia)
                                {
                                    if (Detener == false)
                                    {
                                        Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
                                        Clases.clicks(0);
                                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }

                                break;

                            case 2:
                                if (pixelColor == Form1.c)
                                {
                                    if (Detener == false)
                                    {
                                        Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
                                        Clases.clicks(0);
                                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
```

Aqui la pregunta como puedo saltarme la captura de pantalla y comprobar directamente el color de los pixeles?

Realmente estoy bastante perdido

Tengo una idea de usar:

```
IntPtr desk = GetDesktopWindow();
IntPtr dc = GetWindowDC(desk);
```

Pero no se exactamente que hacer, si alguien me puede ayudar aqui dejo esta pregunta.

Comment: A que te refieres cuando dices "comprobar directamente el color de los pixeles"?

Comment: Me refiero al paso 1 cuando tomo la captura de pantalla, no quiero tomar captura de pantalla quiero hacerlo a tiempo real

Comment: Pero el proceso que quieres hacer requiere analizar lo que se muestra en la pantalla o solo la posicion en la que esta el mouse?

Comment: Intenta trabajarlo en el Metodo Load de la Ventada ya que este siempre esta activo mientras tengas abierta una ventana.

Comment: De eso si hay forma de comprobarlo siempre lo que quiero saber es de donde saco esos valores